# Floating JButton in left corner

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jbutton

I have a huge `JPanel` so it is scrollable. In this `JPanel` I have `JButton` at the right corner. When I want to push it I always need to scroll here. Is it possible to have floating `JButton` at the right corner of my application ?

if yes please help me

Comment: If you could clarify a bit, it would certainly help.  Do you want the button to always follow the scroll and be in the upper right hand of the displayed corner?  Can you place it on another panel so it is always accessible that way, or does it have to 'float' on your original panel?

Comment: yes I wanna to folow scroll wo when I scrol it down up left or right i will always stay in right corner. Iand yes I can place this button to another panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `JWindow` and put there `JButton`, this container you can stick to the right corner of `JViewPort`

Comment: +1 idea, but what layout? I'd not seen [`ViewportLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ViewportLayout.html) before.

Answer (score 2):

The method [`setDefaultButton()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29) may allow you to use the button without scrolling or hiding data under a floating component.

Comment: +1 I saw a translucent Window (autohide on some period, on MouseFocused this Window lost translucency) with some Components, :-) wrote in C++, but I can's see any differene on visual level